# como eu salvo valores de variáveis em um banco de dados mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, opencv

Estou tentando criar um sistema de reconhecimento facial usando o Opencv para registrar o acesso dos usuários ao laboratório da escola mas o problema é que eu não estou conseguindo salvar as informações de horário de acesso de cada usuário e nem a imagem dele na hora que ele entrou. Eu estou usando esse codigo

```
import MySQLdb
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

classificador = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
reconhecedor = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
reconhecedor.read("classificadorLBPH.yml")
largura, altura = 220, 220
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
banco_de_dados = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', host='127.0.0.1', 
database='acesso_usuarios')
cursor = banco_de_dados.cursor()
hora = datetime.now()
while (True):
    conectado, imagem = camera.read()
    imagemCinza = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    facesDetectadas = classificador.detectMultiScale(imagemCinza,
                                                 scaleFactor=1.5,
                                                 minSize=(150, 150))


    for (x, y, l, a) in facesDetectadas:
        imagemFace = cv2.resize(imagemCinza[y:y + a, x:x + l], (largura, altura))
        id, confianca = reconhecedor.predict(imagemFace)
        regiao = imagem[y:y + a, x:x + l]
        cv2.putText(imagem,
                str(hora.day) + '/' + str(hora.month) + '/' + str(hora.year) + '-' + str(hora.hour) + ':' + str(
                    hora.minute) + ':' + str(hora.second), (0, 20), font, 1.5, (0, 255, 0))

        if np.average(imagemCinza) > 110:

            chegada = str(hora.hour) + '-' + str(hora.minute) +'-'+ str(hora.second) +' '+ str(hora.day) +'/'+ str(hora.month) +'/'+ str(hora.year)
            nome = ''
            if id == -1:
                nome = 'desconhecido'
            elif id == 1:
                nome = 'William'
            elif id == 2:
                nome = 'Isaac'
            elif id == 3:
                nome = 'ivamberg'
            elif id == 4:
                nome = 'afonso'

            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM acesso_usuarios.'+nome)
            arg = 'INSERT INTO' +nome+ '(hora_chegada) VALUES %s'
            val = chegada
            cursor.execute(arg, val)
            if np.average(imagemCinza) < 110 or (id != 1):
                hora_de_saida = datetime.now()

                saida = str(hora_de_saida.hour) + str(hora_de_saida.minute) + str(hora_de_saida.second) + str(
            hora_de_saida.day) + str(hora_de_saida.month) + str(hora_de_saida.year)
                arg = 'INSERT INTO' +nome+ '(hora_saida) VALUES %s'
                val = saida
                cursor.execute(arg, val)

            cv2.putText(imagem, nome, (x, y + (a + 30)), font, 2, (0, 0, 255)) 
            cv2.putText(imagem, str(confianca), (x, y + (a + 50)), font, 1, (0, 0, 255))  

        cv2.imshow("Face", imagem)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mas sempre que eu executo da esse erro

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Gear\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 238, in execute
>       query = query % args
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Gear\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\teste.py", line 49, in 
>       cursor.execute(arg, val)
>     File "C:\Users\Gear\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 240, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))
>     File "C:\Users\Gear\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 52, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorclass(errorvalue)
>   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Existe uma tabela para cada nome de usuário ? Porque da forma como você está inserindo(INSERT INTO nome (hora_chegada) VALES %s) da a entender que cada usuário é uma própria Entidade e caso você ainda não tenha criado essa entidade no banco é como tentar inserir os dados na Tabela João sem que a tabela João exista. Poderia mostrar a estrutura da tabela que deve receber o INSERT ? Assim ficará mais fácil ajudarmos

Comment: sim cada usuário tem sua própria tabela